# Game mechanics in Sakura Clicker

Tags: sakura-clicker

Sakura Clicker is a free game on Steam with paid DLC. You click on enemies until they die, yielding gold. You can hire increasingly expensive allies as well as upgrade them, which attack automatically.

I have not found any resources online which explain the numbers involved, which are:

- Gold per enemy slain per L/SL
- Initial cost and damage  of i-th ally
- Cost and damage of k-th upgrade of i-th ally

(A short reminder: An opponent is defined by its HP only. Bosses are stronger and have a 30 second time limit. Levels increase from 1, 2, ... infinitely with each consisting of 5 sub-levels (e.g. 1-1, 1-2, ... 1-5, 2-1, ... 27-5, ...33-3...), and the higher level and sub-level (L/SL) are, the more HP enemies have.)

I believe the formulas are pretty simple. For instance, I believe from observation that the damage of the i-th ally at k-th level is `basedamage(i) * 1.1^k`.

Any bonuses gained from special abilities are of no particular interest. They are very easy to calculate and incorporate anyway.

Comment: This seems a bit broad. Are you sure we can answer your question without writing a complete and comprehensive game guide?

Comment: @DJPirtu Yes. It is a very simple clicker game, it should be only 3 or 4 formulas. I suppose each of them not even half a line long.

I would try to find them myself with probably just an excel sheet, which probably would not take more than a few hours of work, though I would like to check first if someone knows about the result already.

Comment: A game guide could be constructed from that with some mathematical optimization (which would not be too difficult most likely), but that is not what I am looking for here. I'm only interested in the formulas.